# libGDX all textures/sprites white blocks

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

In the Android version of my test program everything is fine on first running it but on running it subsequently all textures are white blocks.

However desktop version is fine, it is only Android. Additionally if I run the program through Eclipse in release or debug it works everytime too.

What fixes it is if I go to task manager and 'clear memory'.

I load my spritesheet on startup and I'm pretty sure I'm disposing everything.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I think I know why but not 100%

In my class: public class GameGraphics implements Disposable{

I made this a singleton:

```
public static GameGraphics getInstance(){
    if(spritesInstance==null) {
        spritesInstance=new GameGraphics();

        spritesInstance.spriteSheet = new   Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/sprite_sheet.png"));
         spritesInstance.sprites=TextureRegion.split(spritesInstance.spriteSheet, 32, 32);
        for(TextureRegion r : spritesInstance.sprites[0]) r.flip(false,true);
    }
    return spritesInstance;
}
```

So dispose was being called, the textured destroyed in libGDX but my instance still remained. Why? Are there any other gotcha's like this with libgdx/opengl?

Comment: This isn't a "gotcha" at all. If you don't reset your instance to `null`, in a self-made Singleton, you cannot consider that a fault of libgdx... You should use the AssetManager for stuff like this. It is specifically designed for this job.

Comment: Cheers, I meant not a fault in libgdx/opengl, but more I read the code a dozen times and it all seemed fine to me. I guess I just assumed that because dispose was being called my pointer would be too :)

I've not looked at AssetManager yet, just starting out.